# Create a list of lists in python with length and count for words

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment where I have to define a function that asks users for a paragraph and creates a list of lists (ex [[x,y],[x1,y2],[x3,y3]) where x = the specified length of a word from the string, and y = count of the words of specified lengths. (ex. [[1,2], [2,3], [4,4], [6,1]]... 1 being a 1 letter word, and 2 being the count of 1 letter words so on so forth.)

This is what I have currently:

```
def wordCount():
   words = []
   wordCount_text_length = []
   word_count = []

   text = input('Please enter a paragaph of regular English text: \n')
   words = (text.split())

   for x in words:
       wordCount_text_length.append(len(x))

   for y in wordCount_text_length:
       word_count.append(wordCount_text_length.count(y))
```

When I run in console and use the phrase "I saw a blue bird." The following is printed (variables for reference):

```
words = ['I', 'saw', 'a', 'blue', 'bird.']
wordCount_text_length = [1, 3, 1, 4, 4]
word_count = [2, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I am stuck because 1.) It is counting punctuation as a part of the string. 2.) How do I create a loop to create the list of lists that will take the word length/count once, and moves on to the next length?

Comment: 1) Look at each character - if it's not a letter, don't count (append) it.

Comment: I was using y as a variable in the for loop for every int in the length list.

Comment: 2) I misread this part the first time.  Think how you would count and keep track of the tally manually of you did not have a computer. Make a note of the *process*.  Like maybe your go through the list counting the number of 1-letter words. Then go through the list again counting the number of 2 letter words. Etc. There are more efficient ways. But this is always a good way to start conceiving your algorithms.  Then turn that process into code. Start with a quick and dirty solution, then optimize, if necessary, as you start to understand the problem-solution better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isalpha()` to filter out punctuation:

```
text = input('Please enter a paragaph of regular English text: \n').split()
new_text = [''.join(b for b in i if b.isalpha()) for i in text]
final_list = [[len(i), ''.join(new_text).count(i.lower())] for i in new_text]
```

Using input of "I saw a blue bird.", the final output is:

```
[[1, 1], [3, 1], [1, 2], [4, 1], [4, 1]]
```

You can also use a dictionary to help visualize your output:

```
final_list = {i.lower():[len(i), ''.join(new_text).count(i.lower())] for i in new_text}
```

Output:

```
{'i': [1, 1], 'saw': [3, 1], 'a': [1, 2], 'blue': [4, 1], 'bird': [4, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a dict and then turn it into a list at the end. I also checked for punctuation using .isalpha(). `sorted(word_lengths.items())` in the last line if you want the final list to be sorted.

```
words = input().split()
word_lengths = {}
puncs = [',', '.']
for word in words:
    y = word
    if not y.isalpha(): y = y[:-1]
    length = len(y)
    try: word_lengths[length] += 1
    except KeyError: word_lengths[length] = 1
print([[k, v] for k, v in word_lengths.items()])
```